# Make autoscaling resources visible in the web console for specific IAM users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I have an AWS account that contains a set of autoscaling groups. I'd like one of my IAM users for that account to be able to see (just read-only ATM) the status of one particular autoscaling group in the IAM user's version of the web console. How do I do that? Right now, the autoscaling group is visible (and can be controlled) through the web console by the account's "root" user, but when the IAM user logs in to his/her specific IAM user account, the autoscaling console webpage shows that no autoscaling groups exist.

I've tried to give the specific IAM user policy permissions for various autoscaling API calls (e.g. autoscaling:Describe*, as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/control-access-using-iam.html)), but that seems to have no impact on the web console for the IAM user, it remains empty (as if no autoscaling groups exist). Is there any other policy I need to give the IAM user permission for, or something else I need to do? Right now they have access to AmazonEC2ReadOnlyAccess and AutoScalingReadOnlyAccess, and some specific API calls so that the python API (boto) works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give it the AutoScalingConsoleReadOnly policy and not just the describe ... You may go to the Policies and there you will find the JSON for the policy

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
            "ec2:DescribeVpcClassicLink",
            "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
            "ec2:DescribeSubnets"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "elasticloadbalancing:Describe*",
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "cloudwatch:ListMetrics",
            "cloudwatch:GetMetricStatistics",
            "cloudwatch:Describe*"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "autoscaling:Describe*",
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "sns:ListSubscriptions",
            "sns:ListTopics"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Once you put this there it should all be fine :),AutoScaling Describe is for you to be able to make the API calls to describe, to access the console the permissions changes considerably